# How to test an method that has like parameter the mock name class

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have one method like this

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $em = $event->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $event->getObject();
    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

}
```

I've tested `getEntityManager` and `getObject` methods, but it is time to test `getClassMetadata` method and each parameters, in this case, it only one !

```
get_class($entity)
```

the above line returns name class (random) :

```
Mock_ObjectManager_126b0394
Mock_ObjectManager_cc9f593f
Mock_ObjectManager_8e119a34
```

it never returns real name class... and I want check the first parameter set when `getClassMetadata` is called.

```
    $test = $this;
    $this->em->expects($this->at(0))
             ->method('getClassMetadata')
             ->with(
                $this->callback(function($arg) use ($test) {
                 $test->assertThat($arg, 
                  $this->logicalAnd(
                   $this->equalTo('ObjectManager')
                  )
                 );//assertThat
                return true;
              }) // callback                                    
             )
             ->willReturn($this->objectManager);
```

How test it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that PHPUnit extends the classes to mock them and assigns them that randomized name. I see two (in my opinion, hackish) options:

First, the worse one, because you need to modify your production code. You could use [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) instead of `get_class()`, so then you'd get `ObjectManager` instead of the mock name. This is obviously not ideal, and if `ObjectManager` is a child class, it won't work at all (*edit* `get_parent_class()` gets the immediate parent, not the upmost parent, so it could still work in that case - *edit2* This won't work. If `ObjectManager` is not a child class, it'll return `false` and fail. Try, instead, instantiating the class from the name inside the test and asserting that it's a child of `ObjectManager`).

The other option, not so bad but still not perfect, is to check if `ObjectManager` is contained in the argument with [`assertContains()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains):

```
$this->callback(function($arg) use ($test) {
    $test->assertContains("ObjectManager", $arg);//assertThat
    return true;
}) // callback
```